# Why won't my PHP return a MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql

Well I have this MySQL stored procedure that I wrote and if I run the following in phpMyAdmin things return properly:

```
SELECT game_name,urlfriendly(game_name) AS game_name2 FROM games
```

However if I try to run the following code I get the error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /filepath.php on line #"

```
foreach ($this->database->query("SELECT game_name,urlfriendly(game_name) AS game_name2 FROM games") as $games)
{
    echo $games["game_name"] . " " . $games["game_name2"];
}
```

However if I run this it all goes fine:

```
foreach ($this->database->query("SELECT game_name FROM games") as $games)
{
    echo $games["game_name"];
}
```

Meaning the stored proc won't return to PHP.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** Here's the stored proc (but I doubt it is the issue as phpMyAdmin is pulling values back from it just fine)

DELIMITER //

```
DROP FUNCTION urlfriendly
//
CREATE FUNCTION urlfriendly (unsafe TEXT) RETURNS TEXT

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

DECLARE safe TEXT;

SET safe = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(unsafe),' ','-'),'&','and'),'`',''),'~',''),'!',''),'@',''),'#',''),'$',''),'%',''),'^',''),'*',''),'(',''),')',''),'_',''),'+',''),'=',''),'[',''),'{',''),']',''),'}',''),'|',''),'\\',''),"'",""),'"',''),':',''),';',''),'<',''),',',''),'>',''),'.',''),'/',''),'?','');

RETURN safe;

END
//
```

**EDIT2** Here is the error returned from MySQL

```
execute command denied to user 'username'@'localhost' for routine 'databasename.urlfriendly' )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you get the [`errorInfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php)?

Can you run:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON `database`.* TO 'username'@'localhost'
```

From phpMyAdmin?

Comment: For PDO you need print_r($this->database->errorInfo()).  I'm guessing it's a permissions thing if it works in phpmyadmin.

Comment: It seems like a permissions issue, any idea how to fix?  (I'll post the actual returned error in the question body)

Comment: I'm getting access denied, I think I may need to talk to my server provider

Comment: Sounds about right, then. I'm not overly familiar with permissions and users and such in MySQL but I think you found your culprit. :)